# Find Maximum Columns in a grouped row. [using PIG]

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have to find maximum number of posts created by person with some given set of data, where I am provided with user id, display name, age, comments count, view count, date, score and title of each post.

To get the number of maximum post, I think, we can group by user id.Now, after grouping, I need to check the id which has the most no. of columns. I don't understand how would I solve the latter part. Please help.

Comment: title is "Find Maximum Columns in a grouped row" and your question is " find maximum number of posts created by person ". I think you edit your question then ask. @Swati

Comment: tell us what exactly your question is ?

Comment: @AnkurSingh , They basically point to the same thing, I want to ask. I am sorry, if I could not make you understand. Let me try once more. I meant to ask, after grouping the datas by id, the output will be details grouped by every id. Now, if I want to find maximum no. of posts, I need to add up the columns,i.e. maximum no. of columns attatched with any id will return us the maximum no. of posts created by any person.

Comment: okay , I am waiting @Swati Sneha

Comment: if possible can you give us you dummy data. So that it is easy to us

Comment: Am I able to clear what I wanted to ask?

Comment: I got your point, but can you give us some dummy data from your dataset.?

Comment: Dataset Description   
Comments.csv-  id  userid  
Posts.csv-  id  post_type  creationdate  score  viewcount  owneruserid  title  answercount  commentcount  
PostTypes.csv-  id  name  
Users.csv-  id  reputation  displayname  loc  age

Comment: Will this be of some help? or, do I need to give the dataset still?

Comment: I can't understand your dataset.!! it so bad type of dataset

Comment: I need dataset because for correct answer , I need to know howz your data look like.

Comment: that is description of dataset. Actually, there are many questions. The questions require all these type of datasets to be solved!

Comment: ok I answer your question. If not correct then comment on the answer I will correct it

Comment: 4,1,2008-07-31 21:42:52,222,13150,8,When setting a form's opacity should I use a decimal or double?,13,34.......
6,1,2008-07-31 22:08:08,98,6691,9,Why doesn't the percentage width child in absolutely positioned parent work in IE 7?,5,12........
7,2,2008-07-31 22:17:57,176,,9,,,0...............
8,1,2008-07-31 23:33:19,30,2432,9,Tool for Converting Visual J# code to C#?,3,0..............
9,1,2008-07-31 23:40:59,582,133946,1,How do I calculate someone's age,37,4............
11,1,2008-07-31 23:55:37,639,59517,1,How do I calculate relative time?,28,9............
12,2,2008-07-31 23:56:41,186,,1,,,11

Comment:  id  post_type  creationdate  score  viewcount  owneruserid  title  answercount  commentcount

Comment: All these are csv with the meaning given in the last comment. I hope this helps you.

Comment: okay I am trying to sove. wait

Comment: I think "maximum column"  is the count no of posts made by each userID. ? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. You got my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As What, I understand from your question. I am giving you answer Accordingly.

Let be try this code :

```
a = load '<path>' using PigStorage(',') as(userId,displayName,age,commentsCount,viewCount,date,score,title)

b = group a by userId;

c = foreach b generate group,COUNT(a.title);

dump c;
```

Comment: Run this code. Is this correct for your question. If not then comment me. @Swati Sneha

Comment: Sure. but, why do you count title? counting Name could have been more relevant. Isn't it?

Comment: where you group by userID then the answer will be not affected. ie.. describe :  Bag{userId , {(  ),(  ),(  )}}.

Comment: After grouping then mainly you have to count no of tuple in that give bag.. ie userId bag

Comment: I missed the keyword count. I am very new to this, actually :(

Comment: Suggestion to you . Next time try to ask complete question. And also mention INPUT and OUTPUT dataset . It will help other to answer your question